# Extracting number between two characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following example data in a column;

```
SPEED_TO_80M_20M_FTTCWBC
SPEED_TO_160M_30M_FTTCFAST
SPEED_TO_24M_WBC
```

I want to extract the first numbers only (80, 160, 24) as numeric using Oracle SQL. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You must explain the rule also, and not treat it as "obvious". Are you looking for the substring immediately following the hard-coded substring `'SPEED_TO_'` and right before the immediately following underscore (or end-of-string), and will that token always be a number followed by `M`, and you must return the numeric part? If the answer is "no" to any of these questions, you must clarify.

Comment: Also - what did you show as the input (and as the output)? Do you have a single, long string, or is your example **three** different strings (in different rows of the input table)?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
Select regexp_substr(your_column, '[0-9]+') 
  From your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for something like such, but it is hard to understand what your rules are. These queries essentially return the answer you are looking for. You would just have to replace the string with the real column names and replace `dual` with the real table name.

```
 select regexp_substr('SPEED_TO_80M_20M_FTTCWBC', '\.*[[:digit:]]+')from dual;
select regexp_substr('SPEED_TO_160M_30M_FTTCFAST', '\.*[[:digit:]]+') from dual;
select regexp_substr('SPEED_TO_24M_WBC', '\.*[[:digit:]]+') from dual;
```